# How does one write positional parameters followed by a digit in a rewrite rule in an nginx.conf file?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, configuration, url-rewriting

I've encountered an nginx.conf file that includes a rewrite rule:

```
rewrite "^(.*/)?8.0/shcb[0-9]+/resources/(.*)" "$18.0/resources/$2";
```

I'm thinking that `$18` is an error. But, I'm not sure if this is like Bash programming where if one has a digit following a positional parameter that the positional parameter must be enclosed in brackets. If so, the above line could be written as:

```
rewrite "^(.*/)?8.0/shcb[0-9]+/resources/(.*)" "${1}8.0/resources/$2";
```

Have I correctly identified a problem and the solution to the problem? I could not find documentation for nginx configuration that says what to do in cases such as the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forms are valid. Nginx only supports `$1` to `$9` for numeric captures, so `$18` looks like $1 followed by a literal `8`.

The use of `{}` is also OK as long as you enclose the expression in quotes.